# Error installing Google-API-Client using cocoapods in iOS

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

I faced problem while installing Google-API-Client for my iOS app, i got following error in terminal.

> [!] Error installing Google-API-Client [!] /usr/bin/svn export
>   --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --force //google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ -r 393
>   /var/folders/3w/401dr8w510vdwk_8x5d_yx1m0000gn/T/d20160531-21031-1o5mmpa
>
> svn: E160013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk' svn:
>   E160013: '//google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
>   path not found

My podfile content is:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'Google-API-Client'

end
```

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your issue but you should have a source at the top of your pod file --> `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

Comment: I added that line at the top of my pod file, still getting same error.

Comment: try to update your plateform to '8.0' instead of '6.0'

Comment: @UmairAfzal I am still facing same error after updating platform from '6.0' to '8.0' in my podfile.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the solution why i am unable to install Google-API-Client using cocoapods. The issue is that i am using "Google-API-Client" which is mentioned in cocoapods doc of Google-API-Client, but it is deprecated naming convention or they are change in their podspec. So i am unable to get that pod.

So the final podfile with right Google-API-Client is as below

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'GoogleAPIClient'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and change directory to your project folder by typing

```
cd ~/"path"
```

- Replace path with your project's folder path
- Then type `pod init`
- Goto your project's folder and open newly created Podfile

your Podfile should look like this

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'YourProjectName' do

pod 'Google-API-Client'

end
```

Save you Podfile and go back to terminal and type

```
pod install
```

Comment: Hi Umair, I have tried this in separate new project, in that also facing the same error. Are you facing the same on your machine?

Comment: I have wrote in podfile : 
pod 'Google-API-Client', :git => 'https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client'

and i got following error : 

[!] Unable to find a specification for 'Google-API-Client'.

[!] Unable to load a podspec from `GoogleAPIClient.podspec`, skipping:

Pod::DSLError

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use which api client you want to use. For example, if you want api client rest. 
    pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Calendar', '~> 1.2.1'. You can use the scope and query service directly possible.

```
Also most important thing is : 
1. Quit Xcode. 
2. Open terminal and change directory to folder containing the xcode file.
3. Pod install. 
4. Open the xcworkspace and wait a moment and BUILD it first with no errors. 
5. Then import the file. Now it will work perfectly.
```